# leaflet.js create map markers from object subset

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, leaflet

Ok, So I have a map I want to add multiple marker groups to. I have an objects called 'years'. I'm trying to create a function that will iterate through 'years' and return a marker from the subset of each year.

I cant quite get to the subset to create the markers. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

The Object:

```
{
    "2016": [
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "latitude": 454545,
            "longitude": 20554,
        "other stuff": "bla0"
        },
        {
            "year": 2016,
            "latitude": 454545,
            "longitude": 20554,
        "other stuff": "bla1"
        }
    ],
    "2017": [
        {
            "year": 2017,
            "latitude": 454545,
            "longitude": 20554,
            "other stuff": "bla2"
        }
    ]
}
```

The Code:

```
function createGroupMarkers(item, i){
    item.map(function(x){   
        marker = new L.marker(
            [x.latitude, x.longitude], // latitude and longitude
            determinIcon(x.year)
        )
    });
    const tempName = [`"${Object.getOwnPropertyNames(item)}"`: this];            
    overlay.push(tempName);
    this.addLayer(marker);
};


const getGroupMarkers = (array, groupName) => array.map(createGroupMarkers.bind(groupName));

const yearMarkers = L.layerGroup().addTo(charMap);

getGroupMarkers(years, yearMarkers);

let overlay = {
    'markers': allMarkers,
};

L.control.layers(null, overlay).addTo(charMap);
```

Any help that could be given would really be appreciated.
I've a WIP pen here: https://codepen.io/sharperwebdev/pen/aqQQZy?editors=0012  the pertinent section starts at line 265

Thanks

Comment: What is the Coordinate Refecence System of your coordinates? Those are sure not degrees of latitude (from -90 to 90) and longitude (-180 to 180)

Comment: it's spoof numbers for illustration. the actual lat and long look like this:  latitude: 51.0504, longitude: 13.7373,